# Looping through rows in a DataView

Tags: .net, loops, dataview

The `DataView` object doesn't have a `Rows` property like `DataTable`.

How do I loop through the rows of a DataView?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

The DataView object itself is used to loop through DataView rows.

DataView rows are represented by the [DataRowView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowview.aspx) object. The [DataRowView.Row](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowview.row.aspx) property provides access to the original DataTable row.

**C#**

```
foreach (DataRowView rowView in dataView)
{
    DataRow row = rowView.Row;
    // Do something //
}
```

**VB.NET**

```
For Each rowView As DataRowView in dataView
    Dim row As DataRow = rowView.Row
    ' Do something '
Next
```

Answer (score 3):

> //You can convert DataView to Table. using DataView.ToTable();

```
foreach (DataRow drGroup in dtGroups.Rows)
{
    dtForms.DefaultView.RowFilter = "ParentFormID='" + drGroup["FormId"].ToString() + "'";

    if (dtForms.DefaultView.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow drForm in dtForms.DefaultView.ToTable().Rows)
        {
            drNew = dtNew.NewRow();

            drNew["FormId"] = drForm["FormId"];
            drNew["FormCaption"] = drForm["FormCaption"];
            drNew["GroupName"] = drGroup["GroupName"];
            dtNew.Rows.Add(drNew);
        }
    }
}
```

> // Or You Can Use
>
> // 2.

```
dtForms.DefaultView.RowFilter = "ParentFormID='" + drGroup["FormId"].ToString() + "'";

DataTable DTFormFilter = dtForms.DefaultView.ToTable();

foreach (DataRow drFormFilter in DTFormFilter.Rows)
{ 
                            //Your logic goes here
}
```

Comment: This is true, it makes sense, and it works. 

My only objection to this approach is the overhead of the processing to convert it back to a table

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to do it in a more direct fashion. It does not have the Rows but is still has the array of rows.

```
tblCrm.DefaultView.RowFilter = "customertype = 'new'";

qtytotal = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < tblCrm.DefaultView.Count; i++)
{
    result = double.TryParse(tblCrm.DefaultView[i]["qty"].ToString(), out num);
    if (result == false) num = 0;
    qtytotal = qtytotal + num;
}

labQty.Text = qtytotal.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate `DefaultView` as the following code by `Indexer`:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
// add some rows to your table
// ...
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "OneColumnName ASC"; // For example
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataRow oRow = dt.DefaultView[i].Row;
    // Do your stuff with oRow
    // ...
}
```