# How to loop through a DataView

Tags: vb.net, loops, dataview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Looping through rows in a DataView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427840/looping-through-rows-in-a-dataview)

I have created a dataview from a datatable.

My question is how can I loop inside the dataview?

I know that in a datatable I can perform a loop like this:

```
For Each oRow as DataRow in iDataset.Tables("tableName")
     Msgbox oRow(0).ToString
Next
```

How do i do that for a `DataView`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1427841/284240

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
For Each rowView As DataRowView in dataView
    Dim row As DataRow = rowView.Row
    Msgbox oRow(0).ToString
Next
```