# Datagrid Issue With Selecting One Cell Out Of A Row

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I am going to try to make it very short and sweet. I have seen how to do this with a datagridview but I can't seem to find it with a normal datagrid. I have a SelectedCellsChanged event that fires off that I want to get a field in a column at the selected row. So when they select an enite row I want to pull the truckercode field so I can do a SQL query on the truckercode cell of that row. I am not doing a Binding for my datagrid. My code for how I fill my data grid is

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("server=Server; database=db; user id=user; password=user"))
{
      connection.Open();
      using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE JOIN OTHERTABLE ON SOMETABLE.TRUCKERCODE = OTHERTABLE.TRUCKERCODE WHERE SOMETABLE.ACTIVE = 1 AND OTHERTABLE.ACTIVE = 1", connection))
      {
             SqlDataAdapter reader = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
             DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
             reader.Fill(dataSet);
             FirstGrid.ItemsSource = dataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
      }
      connection.Close();
      connection.Dispose();
}
```

I think based on [DataGrid Get Selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121186/datagrid-get-selected-rows-column-values?rq=1) I think my code should look similar to

```
private void FirstGrid_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid grid = sender as DataGrid;
        DataRowView row = grid.SelectedItems as DataRowView;
        MessageBox.Show("" + grid.SelectedItems.Count);
        if (grid.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(row["TruckerCode"].ToString());
        }
    }
```

But I get a Argument out of range exception.

Another helpful post is [Looping Through A DataView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427840/looping-through-rows-in-a-dataview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Solved my own problem. I hope anyone that reads this in the future that wants to get a value from selected columns from an entire selected row would use this. This example would print each cell for however many rows they have selected.

```
var grid = FirstGrid.SelectedItems;
foreach(DataRowView row in grid)
{
    if (grid.Count == 1)
    {
       MessageBox.Show(row["NameOfTheColumn"].ToString());
    }
}
```

If you add the grid.Count == 1 it prevents multiple rows from firing off your code. So you only have 1 row in the DataRowView otherwise you may have multiple DataRowViews.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a CellClick handler in your dataGrid

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="235,12,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="218" Width="501" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <EventSetter Event="GotFocus" Handler="CellClick"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Following method will then be triggered in your background class, once the user clicks on a cell in the dataGrid. 'index' is the value the selected cell includes:

```
void CellClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridCell cell = sender as DataGridCell;
        string index = cell.Column.DisplayIndex.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: That is nice and all but I want to get a certain cell when the entire row is selected not making the user click on that given cell themselves.